# How to "inherit" an iterator from an STL class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, stl, iterator

I'm trying to create a class of objects called tableaux, which are essentially vectors of vectors of unsigned ints (they're like matrices except the rows can be different lengths) with some algorithms I have written. The main problem is that I want to inherit iterators  for these objects from the vector class and I don't know how.

I've read several related questions and answers, and it's pretty easy for me to just inherit `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> >` publicly, but the consensus is that this is bad for reasons of STL containers not having virtual destructors or whatever. So I've decided to try and "inherit" by composition. Here is a somewhat-minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class tableau {
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > rep;
  public:
    using std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> >::iterator;
    void push_back(std::vector<unsigned int> const& new_row) {
      rep.push_back(new_row);
    }
};

int main() {
  tableau t1;
  std::vector<unsigned int> row1(10);
  std::vector<unsigned int> row2(8);

  t1.push_back(row1);
  t1.push_back(row2);

  tableau::iterator it = t1.begin();
  for ( ; it != t1.end(); ++it) {
    //display rows of tableau
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But then g++ gives me the error: type '`std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> >`' is not a base type for type 'tableau'. I'm just starting to learn C++ so please be gentle if I did something stupid. If you want more of the actual code I have written, let me know.

Comment: In general, this is a very good testcase. Well done. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first problem is that `using` doesn't allow you to steal types from arbitrary unrelated types (though you could use `typedef` for this). Also, you have no `begin()` or `end()` members.

Resolving these issues results in the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class tableau {
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > rep;
  public:
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> >::iterator iterator;
    void push_back(std::vector<unsigned int> const& new_row) {
      rep.push_back(new_row);
    }
    iterator begin() { return rep.begin(); }
    iterator end()   { return rep.end();   }
};

int main() {
  tableau t1;
  std::vector<unsigned int> row1(10);
  std::vector<unsigned int> row2(8);

  t1.push_back(row1);
  t1.push_back(row2);

  tableau::iterator it = t1.begin();
  for ( ; it != t1.end(); ++it) {
    //display rows of tableau
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, your approach means you're going to have to wrap every single function you want to call.

**If I were you I'd stick with inheritance**: though the advice you cite is correct, that doesn't mean inheritance is impossible. You're never going to want to use your `tableau` polymorphically through a pointer-to-base, so simply document that nobody should ever try to do this, and you'll be fine.

<sup>(When you make use of "composition" it's called "composing". You're asking how to "compose" the vector.)</sup>

Comment: Ok, the concept of composing makes a lot more sense now, thanks. I think I will just stick with inheritance in this case.

Comment: @Joseph: I think that's wise.

Comment: +1 Inheritance of containers isn't nearly as bad as some people try to make it.